# Macbook is not starting up / random shut down

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, screen, shutdown

I was working on illustrator and suddenly my laptop went off, and is now failing to boot. Random lines are appearing on my screen as it tries to boot. Below is a link to a video I made of the issue:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=79b5ThdXIjM

Comment: I had a siilar problem and fixed it with cleaning dust from the inside. Did you recognize your computer is getting hot?